# Redirect with RewriteRule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

How to redirect with RewriteRule?
from:

```
www.example.com/ca/blog/something
```

To:

```
www.example.com/ca/test.php?url=something
```

Of course "something" could change. The other parts of the url will always be the same.
In the end, I want to use `test.php` with a parameter set:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

I have deleted all other rules in the .htaccess to be sure there is no conflict. Please explain the solution. I am very new to regex.

Comment: What is wrong with the question, Why the negative point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ca/blog/(.*)$ /ca/test.php?url=$1 [L,R=301]
```

It captures everything after `/blog/` and gives it as an parameter to `test.php`. The period (.) means "every character", the asterisk (*) means "as many as I can possibly find (or none)", the brackets will capture the result. If you want to make sure that the url parameter in `test.php` is not empty, you might want to use a plus (+) like so:

```
RewriteRule ca/blog/(.+)$ /ca/test.php?url=$1 [L,R=301]
```

This means "as many characters but there has to be at least one". Additionally, there [is a nice online tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) for this.

Comment: If I write your solution in the bowser: The requested URL /ca/blog/something was not found on this server. If write www.example.com/ca/test.php?url=something I get: "something"

Comment: Where did you put your `.htaccess` file? It must reside in the root folder.

Comment: Yes, it is in the root folder. Yesterday I had other rules that worked. I do not know why, I just have problems with this

Comment: See my updated answer, try it without the "^" at the beginning.

Comment: If there are others "RewriteRule", should I put "RewriteEngine On" before each "RewriteRule" or just once?

Comment: Once at the top of the file.

Comment: It works well, thank you. Why is it necessary the "/" in the second part if is not in the first part? ca... /ca...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
# at the entrance of RewriteRule: ca/blog/something
RewriteRule ^ca/blog/(.*)$ ca/test.php?url=$1 [QSA]
# after transformation: "ca/blog/something" -> "ca/test.php?url=something"
```

Comment: Why "RewriteBase /" I suppose I have to put "RewriteEngine On" before, too?

Comment: @Nrc yep, you should write `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning of the file. I think `RewriteBase ` not necessary in your case.

Comment: @Nrc When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: I do not see why is this necessary here? If I understand: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html This is a complication for a very specific case